# How to email the saved document not the orig document through VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

This is what I want it to do.  They open the document, fill in the form and when they hit the submit button it will print the filled in document, save it as a different name with user input and then is supposed to email the new document with the data too.  Everything is working except it is not e-mailing the new document.

I need either the complete document they have filled in to be emailed or the content that they filled in as an attachment.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
Application.ActiveDocument.PrintOut
Dim strDocName As String
    Dim intPos As Integer
  'Ask the user to provide a filename
        strDocName = InputBox("Please enter the name " & _
            "of your document.")
ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName, _
        FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument

Options.SendMailAttach = True
ActiveDocument.SendMail

End Sub
```

Comment: What is currently happening? Is there no document attached at all?

Comment: It saves the new document but the doc on my screen is still the orig one and that is what gets attached instead of new doc.

Answer (score 1):

At some point, "ActiveDocument" switches from the new document to the old one.  You must refer to the new one explicitly.

I'm not sure at what point the switchover occurs, but try this.

Change:

```
Options.SendMailAttach = True
ActiveDocument.SendMail
```

To:

```
Dim MailDoc as Document
Set MailDoc = ActiveDocument

Options.SendMailAttach = True
MailDoc.SendMail
```